# Need Help to solve and understand this error: Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: 2

Tags: c#, database, razor, webmatrix

I got this error:

> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: 2 : String truncation: max=0, len=1, value='3'.

From this set of code:

```
var reqcategory=Request["category"];
foreach (var cat in reqcategory)
{
    var sql5 = "SELECT Type.PreReq1, Type.PreReq2, 
                       (CASE WHEN (Type.PreReq1 IS NOT NULL)
                             AND (PermitApp1.RPClass IS NULL) 
                             AND (PermitApp1.RPCategory IS NULL) 
                        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS missing1, 
                       (CASE WHEN (Type.PreReq2 IS NOT NULL) 
                             AND (PermitApp2.RPClass IS NULL)
                             AND (PermitApp2.RPCategory IS NULL) 
                        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS missing2 
                FROM Type LEFT JOIN PermitApp AS PermitApp1 
                     ON (Type.PreReq1=PermitApp1.RPClass) 
                       OR (Type.PreReq1=PermitApp1.RPCategory) 
                           AND ( PermitApp1.CDSID = @0 ) 
                           AND (PermitApp1.MDecision='1') 
                          LEFT JOIN PermitApp AS PermitApp2 
                     ON (Type.PreReq2=PermitApp2.RPClass) 
                       OR (Type.PreReq2=PermitApp2.RPCategory) 
                           AND ( PermitApp2.CDSID = @1 ) 
                           AND (PermitApp2.MDecision='1') 
                WHERE Type.PType = @2";

    var result = db.QuerySingle(sql5, myCDSID, username, cat);
    var miss1 = result.missing1;
    var miss2 = result.missing2;

    if(miss1 == '1' || miss2 == '1'){
        ModelState.AddError("missing", 
                  "You have not met the Pre-Requisites for "+ cat +" yet.");
    } else if (miss1 == '0' && miss2 == '0'){
        Session["license"] = Request["licence"];
        Session["from"] = Request["from"];
        Session["to"] = Request["to"];
        Session["group"] = Request["group"];
        Session["class1"] = Request["class1"];
        Session["category1"] = Request["category1"];
        Session["class"] = Request["class"];
        Session["category"] = Request["category"];
        Response.Redirect("~/Questionnaire");
    }
}
```

the highlighted line was :

```
var result = db.QuerySingle(sql5, myCDSID, username, cat);
```

I don't understand what was mentioned on the error page and I could not find someone in the same case as my. Thanks

Comment: And did you test that horrendous SQL statement in Mgmt Studio first? Does it work?

Comment: Does one of the params (myCDSID) have the value '3' ?

Comment: Yea tested SQL query is working perfectly as what I wanted but not sure about the variables...wat is params?

Comment: Param[eter]s are the @0, @1, @2 values

Comment: Oh nope none of the parameters have 3 it's all string

Comment: Still, what are the values of `myCDSID` and `cat` just before it bombs?

Comment: hmm CDSID will be for example 8 characters for example if first name is steve and last name is gates then the CDSID will be SGATES123, which is already defined in the users table...and for cat...that is the problem...I am not too sure either...according to the code it suppose to be defined in `foreach (var cat in reqcategory)`

Comment: Try `foreach (string cat in reqcategory) ...`

Comment: Yeah that foreach looks a little suspect to me... what are you expecting to find in Request["category"]?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't speak for your SQL query, as I don't think I've ever seen a query like that, but it has been my experience that when a query is made and that error is returned, provided that it is a valid sql query at all, it means that a string had to be 'truncated' because the database field is set to store less characters than you are trying to pass into the field.

That is, as an example, a string, say 60 characters long, is being passed into a field set at, say nvarchar(50).  Try adjusting the number of bytes allowed to be stored in the string field(s).

Not totally sure if this is your issue, as I'm still new to a lot of this, myself, but just thought it could be a possibility, as that has been something that I have seen happen to me a few times before.

Hope I helped!